# Delete question and reverse reputation changes made while it was up

Tags: support, reputation, deleted-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

Does deleting your own question reverse the reputation changes (whether up or down) from votes cast while the question was still up?

Comment: [Please search a while before asking a question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7237/187824)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Does one deleting their own question, reverse the reputations changes (up and down) caused by votes while the question was open?*

**YES**, except in below cases

1. Reputation earned for posts with a score of 3 or higher, and where the post has been visible on the site for at least 60 days, is retained.
2. Reputation lost as a penalty for having a post deleted by flagging is not returned.

Comment: Thanks Krishnabhadra - Seems a sad thing to want to do, but think people are not voting according to the alt tag reasons for downvoting, but instead because they think the question is silly, or something. As reputation is important, what I think (and am sure other sets of people will too) are well intended / helpful questions, will be no more.

Comment: Assuming this comes from some part of the FAQ. Instead of me asking more questions in the comments, perhaps you could cite a permalink to / near the info I seem to be interested in?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that